# Got errors when the project was updated with three.min.js (revision 55)

Tags: three.js

I haven't updated my project for a while (it is based on three.js library) and when I did it recently (with three.min.js: revision 55) I got the following errors:

With the following line I got "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" with:

```
axe_b.geometry.materials[0].opacity = opacity;
```

What should I change in these lines to make it running?

With the previous version of three.js the above code was fine.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading to the current version.

`TrackballControls.js` is part of the examples now, and must be added explicitly. See the three.js examples.

`Materials` are no longer part of `Geometry`.

three.js r.55

Answer (score 0):

THREE.TrackballControls is no longer part of three.js or three.min.js.  It is now in example/js/controls/TrackballControls.js so you'll need to add something similar to this in the head of you HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```

Materials are in the mesh in a variable called material so yours may now be in

```
axe_b.material.materials[0].opacity = opacity;
```

or

```
axe_b.material.opacity = opacity;
```

Depending on whether you've defined a list of materials for a mesh or just one material.